# Is it possible to find the explicit inverse of $I+AB$, where $A$ is diagonal and $B$ symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices

> **Question.** Is it possible to find the explicit inverse of $I+AB$, where $A$ is diagonal and $B$ symmetric matrix?

$A$, $B$ are non-singular, and $I+AB$ is invertible. For $B=S-I$, where $S=[s_{ij}]=[c*sinc(c\pi(i-j))]$, $i$ and $j$ are row and column indices, $sinc(x)=sin(x)/x$, $0<c<1$

It is equivalent to find the explicit inverse of $A_0+B$ where $A_0$ is diagonal and $B$ symmetric matrix.

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: To get a feeling for what you mean by "explicit inverse", how would a possiblbe answer for $1\times 1$ matrices look?

Comment: The given conditions do not imply that an inverse exists, so it seems the short answer is no.  Is there more information about $A,B$, especially about their *positivity*?

Comment: For example, if $A=I$ (diagonal) and $B=-I$ (symmetric), then $I+AB=0$ is not invertible.

Comment: One has to provide that $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $AB$.

Comment: Thank you all for kind feedback. More conditions are added to guarantee the existence of the inverse :-)